# Do we actually test the 'Fixture' when using FitNesse?

Tags: fixture, fitness

This is more of a discussion I guess, and I would like to hear the opinions of others who use FitNesse.

I'm quite new to FitNesse and was reading for last few days. I understand the concepts of the 'test wiki' and the 'Fixtures' and the test runs against the fixture. However I wasn't very clear around the link between the fixture and the SUT. When we run the test, do we actually test the fixture? Isn't the test result as good as the fixture being used? How do we link the fixture with the SUT.

I'm sorry if these are fundamental questions, but I could not find a satisfactory answer so far. Appreciate your opinion / feedback on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When you run the test you use the fixture to test the SUT. Of course the fixture itself can have issues and has to be tested too. It is good practice to make a demo suite in which you document and test all fixtures. Note that errors and mistakes can be made everywhere. If a test fails, it should indicate a problem with the SUT but the problem can also be in the wiki or the fixtures.

Comment: Thanks Michiel. Appreciate your time on this. So the fixture itself is a replica of the SUT? Unless we have all the methods (or the modules being tested)  of SUT implemented in fixtures, our test wouldn't be accurate, isn't it?

Comment: No, the fixture is not a replica of the SUT. It is an interface to the SUT, it makes it possible to test the SUT with FitNesse.

Comment: I see. Got it. Thanks Michiel.